# A construction related to scissors congruence

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convexity, scissors-congruence

I was thinking about the following some time ago. My question is whether such things have been studied before.

Let $E_n$ be the abelian group with a generator for each (bounded) euclidean polytope of dimension at most $n$ and relations (1) $P=Q$ if $P$ and $Q$ are congruent, (2) $P\cup Q=P+Q-P\cap Q$, (3) $\emptyset=0$.

Clearly the cokernel of the obvious map $E_{n-1}\to E_n$ is the usual $n$-th euclidean scissors congruence group.

Comment: The answer is yes. The masters in this domain are Sah, Dupont, Cathelineau and Goncharov. You'll find a very precise and elegant analysis of the congruence groups and Dehn invariants in *Scissors Congruences, Group Homology and Characteristic Classes* by Dupont. Goncharov and Cathelineau are more on a way of generalizing this stuff to other fields of definitions and finding links with (Milnor) K-theory.

Comment: Does Dupont consider exactly this? Note that I am not declaring $P$ to be $0$ in $E_n$ if $P$ has dimension less than $n$.

Comment: You're right, not exactly. I'd guess that the two points of view are equivalent, but it would need to be checked. Tell us !

Answer (score 2):

For P=Q if P and Q are translates (instead of (1)), the so-called polytope algebra is obtained (see Peter McMullen, Advances 1989). The polytope algebra has found important applications in the theory of polytopes (McMullen 1993) and the theory of valuations on convex polytopes.